# Docker behing transparent proxy and intermediate cert

Tags: docker, ssl, centos, tls1.2, dockerhub

OS: Centos 7.6.1810
Docker Version:  Server Version: 18.09.5

Issue:
My company uses a transparent proxy with an intermediate cert to navigate. I was able to install the cert following doc: https://docs.docker.com/ee/dtr/user/access-dtr/ and these steps:

```
# Download the DTR CA certificate
sudo curl -k https://<dtr-domain-name>/ca -o /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/<dtr-domain-name>.crt
# Refresh the list of certificates to trust
sudo update-ca-trust
# Restart the Docker daemon
sudo /bin/systemctl restart docker.service
```

Curl and Wget are working well, but docker run is not:

```
bash $ docker run -it cheers
Unable to find image 'cheers:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: remote error: tls: handshake failure.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I've tried adding the registry as insecure in daemon.json but it was unsuccessfully.

Has anyone run into the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured out what’s going on:

Docker client offers only TLS_ECDHE_* ciphers but .docker.io (behind my corporate proxy) offers only TLS_RSA ciphers.

Without proxy, docker.io offers both types of ciphers.

Now, next challenge: make docker offer TLS_RSA or make my proxy support TLS_ECDHE.

I have no idea how to do either :frowning: